# How to get a canonical url for a dynamically generated urls on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, canonical-link

I implemented canonical url for homepage as follows: I added this line

```
  <link rel='canonical' href='https://example.com/'>
```

I added this line on `index.html.erb` in `header` section. It is working fine.

Now I have dynamic routes generating line as follows:

```
<a href "<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.id) %>">
```

I tried with following:

```
<a rel='canonical' href="<%= search_equipments_path(:category_id => category.slug) %>">
```

But didn't work.

Answer (score 8):

We can set canonical tags in rails this way. This rails code will output canonical tags for full current url. Add this in layout in HTML head section.

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="<%= url_for(:only_path => false) %>" />
```

You can also specify the default protocol to be use for this URL by using:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<%= url_for(:only_path => false, :protocol => 'https') %>" />
```

For more options please refer this [link](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added this on application.html.erb. Worked for all the urls except for this `http://example.com/equipment_details/equipment-5`. How can I fix this?

Comment: and my site is running on `https`. But after implementing your solution it is giving `http` canonical url. How can I fix this?

Comment: But it is working fine on my website on https (godaddy), I've used the same and the SEO guy said okay for the solution. I'll check if anything else required...

Comment: hi @Mayank i followed your solution , it worked but i have the same http issue as mentioned above.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it breaks as soon as the route takes any parameters - like the show action or with nested resources. This doesn't actually generate the current url - it uses the current controller and action name to make a wild guess about the route. If you want the current request URL you can get it from the request.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `content_for` to create a dynamic chunk in the header section of your layout:

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    # ...
    <% if content_for?(:canonical_url) -%>
      <%= tag :link, href: content_for(:canonical_url), rel: 'canonical' %>
    <% end -%>
  </head>
</html>
```

You can then provide the `canonical_url` in your views:

```
<%= provide(:canonical_url, search_equipments_url(category.slug)) %>
```

Comment: This seems far more straightforward than including a gem or even a rack middleware. The latter seems quite overly complex. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Kjell no not really - `content_for` does come with the warning `WARNING: content_for is ignored in caches. So you shouldn't use it for elements that will be fragment cached.`. But other then that its a pretty simple solution to providing dynamic content. You can even have it default to having `url_for` make wild guesses.

Comment: @Kjell I didn't actually consider the middleware approach but it definately has some merit in that you can just set the canonical URL header from the controller and not worry about doing anything in your views and you could potentially use the same solution for any content type.