# Dynamic canonical tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, canonical-link

Lately, I've been making my site more SEO friendly. Everything has been fun and games
until the canonical tag came along.

My site index is structured like the following.

- `example.com/all` show all products.
- `example.com/all?brand=levis` shows all products from Levi's.
- `example.com/jeans` shows all jeans.

I would want to have dynamic canonical tags that refer to `mysite.com/all`, `mysite.com/all?brand=current-brand` and `mysite.com/current-category`.

The site also has a filter option for color and brands which produces slugs like `mysite.com/hoodies?color=grey` and `mysite/hoodies?brand=nike&color=green`. In both cases, I would want to have a canonical referring to `mysite.com/hoodies`

I made an attempt to fix this with an if else solution without success.

How it's set up now is like the following:

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<%= yield :canonical %>
```

**views/pages/about**

```
<%= content_for :canonical do %>
<link rel="canonical" href="example.com/about/" />
<% end %>
```

**views/products/show**

```
<% content_for :canonical do %>
<link rel="canonical" href="<%="example.com/#{@product.id}/"%>" />
<% end %>
```

These two works fine but when it comes to the index page it becomes trickier.

First I tried

```
<% content_for :canonical do %>
<link rel="canonical" href="<%="example.com/#{@category.slug}/"%>" />
<% end %>
```

This solution works fine when you go by category but crashes when you go to `mysite.com/all` or  `mysite.com/all?brand=levis`.

I tried to experiment with some if else statements where I tried to target the current slug but it all ended up with crashes.

Do you guys have any suggestions of what I can do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a canonical url for a dynamically generated urls on rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434601/how-to-get-a-canonical-url-for-a-dynamically-generated-urls-on-rails)

Comment: Please show your attempt. Explain what you want it to do, what's wrong with it, and show the error message (if any). See: [mcve].

Comment: @TomLord Thanks for the response. An example is now added to the question.

Comment: @ramblex Maybe, I'll check it out and see!

Answer (score 0):

I somewhat solved the problem by placing

```
<% content_for :canonical do %>
<link rel="canonical" href="<%="example.com/#{@category.slug}/"%>" />
<% end %>
```

Under

```
<% if @category %>
```

It does not work exactly as I described in the questing since there is no canonical for `example.com/all?brand=levis` nor `example.com/all`. But that might even be better for SEO since google might take `/all` and `/jeans` for duplicate content, I'm not 100% sure. If you have another better solution, share and I would be more than happy!